# PHP : Fpdf adding text right after the image

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to build  a logo in FPDF  but I want to add a text beside of it. I am using this library http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script70.php

[image: Add Image]

```
$pdf=new PDF_HTML_Table();
$pdf->AddPage();
$Image1 = '../../assets/LogoSystemName.png';
$pdf->Image($Image1, 5, null, 50); //Image
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->WriteHTML("Rubric for event: ".$soc['event_name']." <br> test 
<br>$htmlTable<br>End of the table.");
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: use table in fpdf , reed this http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm

Comment: I am using fdpf library please take a look on my link i edited question